# How are the $$ functions used in this pure JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript

This code is in a tutorial I'm taking, and it logs all heading tags on a page in their order in the DOM. Can someone explain how this code works? (In particular the part `headings = $$('h1,h2...')`)

What are the $$ characters denoting?

```
for (var i = 0, headings = $$('h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6');
     i < headings.length; i++) {
   console.log(headings[i].textContent.trim() + " " +  
               headings[i].tagName,
               headings[i]);
}
```

Comment: Could be anything - you would have to look at the page to see where the function `$$` is defined (though it's probably `querySelectorAll` or jQuery)

Comment: `$` is a character that can be used just like letters in JavaScript function and variable names. If that code is *all* the code that you're being shown, I would have some questions about the quality of the tutorial.

Comment: If I run " headings = $$('h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6');" in the Chrome console of pages with no other javascript or jQuery, it returns an array of all the headings on that page. The tutorial is on accessibility and this snippet was not the point of the lesson, but I am trying to understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments it is probably a wrapper function for `document.querySelectorAll()` or other dom query method(s)

```js
function $$(selectors) {
  return document.querySelectorAll(selectors)
}

for (var i = 0, headings = $$('h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6'); i < headings.length; i++) {
  console.log(headings[i].textContent.trim() + " " +
    headings[i].tagName,
    headings[i]);
}
```

```html
<h1>One</h1>
<h2>Two</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. It is a Console Utilities API convenience function that can only be run from the console. This $$ is basically a built-in console shortcut for querySelectorAll. 
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/utilities